# Android own ArrayAdapter implementation

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I`m trying to separate implementation of ArrayAdapter from activity class.
So far I moved it to separate class but getSystemService() is causing me problems.

I`ve tried to pass context on constructor like this

```
public KontaktAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Kontakt> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.context    =   context;
```

But none of following works

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

EDIT : finally this seems to work for me now

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```